# Creating various arrays from a string using LOOPS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a string of values

```
"000111111122222223333333444455556666"
```

How could I use a loop to produce one array for index values from 0 to 3 (create an array of [000] and then another array of index values from 3 to 10, 10 to 17, 17 to 24, producing eg. [1111111, 2222222, 333333] and then another loop to produce an array of index values from 24 to 28, 28 to 32, 32 to 36, producing eg. [4444, 5555, 6666])?

So in total 3 different arrays have been created using three different for loops.

```
array1 = [000]
array2 = [1111111, 2222222, 333333]
array3 = [4444, 5555, 6666]
```

Comment: if I understand correctly you want to separate value by their quantity in the string ? What would be the expected output from `0112`, `01100` and `0110`

Comment: Please provide your desired output, from what you've written it's a bit hard to tell what you want for the final outcome

Comment: what is with your last question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910212/splicing-string-values-using-functions-and-loops-and-storing-as-an-array

Comment: @NinaScholz even if it is REALLY close it is not exactly the same, this time he want to output differents array, maybe with not defined size for each parts

Comment: and btw, no attempt.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free codew writing service. Show what you have tried. The objective here is for others to help fix **your code** not do all the work for you

Comment: I'm very very sorry for not uploading my attempts @NinaScholz and charlietfl I just had so many that didn't work that I wasn't sure which one to upload. I certainly will next time, thank you very much for your help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"000111111122222223333333444455556666".match(/(.)\1*/g).reduce((out, v) => ((out[out.length-1] && out[out.length-1][0].length === v.length)?out[out.length-1].push(v):out.push([v]), out), []);`

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to try something line this (only a schematic solution!):

```
var l_Input = "000111111122222223333333444455556666" ;

var l_Array_1 = [] ;
var l_Array_2 = [] ;
var l_Array_3 = [] ;


var l_One_Char ;

for (var i = 0 ; i < l_Input.length ; i++) {

    l_One_Char = l_Input.substring(i,i) ;

    if (i < 3) {
        l_Array_1.push(l_One_Char) ;
        continue ;
    }

    if (i >= 3 && i < 10) {
        l_Array_2.push(l_One_Char) ;
        continue ;
    }
    :
    :
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work.

```
const str = '000111111122222223333333444455556666';

function makeArr(str, item) {
    let firstIndex = str.indexOf(item);
    let lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf(item) + 1;
    return [ str.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex) ];
}

const first = makeArr(str, 0);
const second = [].concat(makeArr(str, 1))
                 .concat(makeArr(str, 2))
                 .concat(makeArr(str, 3));
const third = [].concat(makeArr(str, 4))
                .concat(makeArr(str, 3))
                .concat(makeArr(str, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the sub strings.

```js
var str = '000111111122222223333333444455556666',
    parts = [[3], [7, 7, 7], [4, 4, 4]],
    result = parts.map((i => a => a.map(l => str.slice(i, i += l)))(0));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function split(string, start, end) {
    var result = [],
        substring = string[start],
        split;

    for (var i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
        var char = string[i];
        if (char === substring[0])
            substring += char;
        else {
            result.push(substring);
            substring = char;
        }
    }
    result.push(substring);
    return result;
}
```

`split("00011122",0,8)`

> ["000", "111", "22"]

Answer (score 0):

To do this dynamically, you can use `.split()` and `.map()` methods to make an `array` from your `string` then group this `array` items by value.

This is how should be our code:

```
const str = "000111111122222223333333444455556666";

var groupArrayByValues = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, x) {
    (a[x] = a[x] || []).push(x);
    return a;
  }, []);
};

var arr = str.split("").map(v => +v);
var result = groupArrayByValues(arr);
```

This will give you an `array` of separate arrays with similar `values` each.

**Demo:**

```js
const str = "000111111122222223333333444455556666";

var groupArrayByValues = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(a, x) {
    (a[x] = a[x] || []).push(x);
    return a;
  }, []);
};

var arr = str.split("").map(v => +v);
var result = groupArrayByValues(arr);


console.log(result);
```